# How to get separate child node values

Tags: java, xml, soap

```
    <hotel hotelCode="FR000715" hotelRating="3STR">
        <hotelName>Kyriad Paris Porte D'Ivry</hotelName>
        <hotelChain code="">Simply Hotels</hotelChain>
        <city code="FRIVS" standard="LOCODE">Ivry-Sur-Seine</city>
        <geoLocalization latitude="48.819761" longitude="2.376128"/>
        <address>1-11, Rue René Villars 94200 Ivry-Sur-Seine</address>
        <phone>00 33 1 46 71 00 17</phone>
        <fax>00 33 1 46 58 91 00</fax>
        <email>email@test.com</email>
    </hotel>
```

I want to get `hotelCode`, `hotelRating`,`hotelName`,`city`,`geoLocalization` from above code

here is my code :

```
        DOMParser parser = DOMParser.getInstance();
        parser.parse(responseStr);
        Document document = parser.getDocument();
        NodeList response = document.getElementsByTagName("hotel");

        for (int hd = 0; hd < response.getLength(); hd++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < response.item(hd).getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
                Node referenceChild = response.item(hd).getChildNodes().item(j);

                if (null != referenceChild.getLocalName()) {
                    if (referenceChild.getLocalName().equals("hotelName")) {
                        hotelName = referenceChild.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Only I can only receive `hotelName`. But not other tags. I want to get all child nodes values separately.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  _"Only I can receive hotelName in this way"_ is ambiguous in English.  Do you mean you can retrieve `hotelName` but not other tags?  Your code retrieves only `hotelName`.  Please [edit] your post and show the complete code that has the problem.

Comment: yes. I can only get `hotelName`. I want to get other child nodes values also separately.

Comment: You have to show us the code that is not working.  As it stands right now your code does not access the other nodes, so we cannot tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "element.getAttribute"

```
for (int hd = 0; hd < response.getLength(); hd++) {
        Node nNode = response.item(hd);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
              hotelCode=eElement.getAttribute("hotelCode");
              hotelRating=eElement.getAttribute("hotelRating");
            for (int j = 0; j < response.item(hd).getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
                Node referenceChild = response.item(hd).getChildNodes().item(j);

                if (null != referenceChild.getLocalName()) {
                    if (referenceChild.getLocalName().equals("hotelName")) {
                        hotelName = referenceChild.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    }
                    else if (referenceChild.getLocalName().equals("city")) {
                        city = referenceChild.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    }
                    else if (referenceChild.getLocalName().equals("geoLocalization")) {
                        if (referenceChild.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eChildElement = (Element) referenceChild;
                            latitude=eChildElement.getAttribute("latitude");
                            longitude=eChildElement.getAttribute("longitude");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

More details please check this link
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm